# How to develop a Slack share button in HTML with onclick?

Tags: html, onclick, share, slack-api, slack

I want to add on my website a Slack share button that would allow users to send a link in the team or the channel of their choice.

For example, I have tags that link to web pages (of my projects) with span inside to click on the sharing "buttons" (which are actually svg) thanks to "onclick".

```
<a href="…">
  <img src="…"/>
    <h2>Name of the project</h2>

      <span class="facebook" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.nameoftheproject.com'); return false">
        <svg>…</svg> <!-- Facebook icon in svg -->
      </span>

      <span class="twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/share?url=https://www.nameoftheproject.com'); return false">
        <svg>…</svg> <!-- Twitter icon in svg -->
      </span>

      <span class="linkedin" onclick="window.open('http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=https://www.nameoftheproject.com'); return false">
        <svg>…</svg> <!-- LinkedIn icon in svg -->
      </span>



      <span class="slack" onclick="window.open('…'); return false">
        <svg>…</svg> <!-- Slack icon in svg -->
      </span>

</a>
```

It's the same principle as Muzli if you know.

So I have difficulty understanding how to proceed with Slack.
if you can help me that would be great, thank you.

Thibaut.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible in the way that you want at the moment 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slack teams are private and access from the "outside" has to be configured for each of them individually and specifically. So each slack team would have to grant your website / app access first to make your "public" share button work. Since this is something a normal user can't do (it requires admin or owner rights) this is not really practical to do.

If you really need to do it here is an idea how it could work:

- You could develop a companion app for the Slack app store.
- Each Slack team that installs this app automatically grants your website
  access    to their Slack team and thus enables your share button.
- Your website could have a "Add to Slack" button for installing the your companion app directly